# Returning to a UIView with data already passed to it

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I have just started developing for iOS. To get right to the point...I created a UITableViewController populated with some audio files I want to play. I have successfully passed the selected rows string, and change views to the 'Now Play View" which is a UIViewController. From there I play the audio using the avaudioplayer. After returning to the previous screen with the embedded navigationcontroller, and selecting a different audio track it creates a whole new instance of the avaudioplayer and plays the newly selected audio on top of the old selected audio with no way of stopping the old one. How do I create a "Now Playing" view where I can load the newly selected audio and clear the old audio??

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface NowPlayingViewController : UIViewController{

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

    //playPause button images
    UIImage *playImg;
    UIImage *pauseImg;

    IBOutlet UIButton *playPauseButton;

    //Volume slider
    NSTimer *volumeTimer;
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;

}

//playPause button action
- (IBAction)playPause:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here is the implementation file.

```
 #import "NowPlayingViewController.h"

    @implementation NowPlayingViewController


    #pragma mark - My actions
    //Audio Player Controllers

    //Play the selected audio.
    - (IBAction)playPause:(id)sender
    {
        if (![audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
            [playPauseButton setImage:pauseImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [audioPlayer play];
        } else { 
            [playPauseButton setImage:playImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [audioPlayer pause];
        }
    }

    -(void)updateVolumeSlider
    {
        [audioPlayer setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
    }

    #pragma mark - Initialization
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //Instantiate needed variables
        playImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play.png"];
        pauseImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"];

        //Prepare the audio player
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.title ofType:@"m4a"];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        //Setup the volume slider
        volumeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(updateVolumeSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

MainView Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController{

    NSMutableArray *performanceArray;
    NSMutableArray *recoveryArray;

}

@end
```

MainView Implementation File

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "NowPlayingViewController.h"


@implementation MainTableViewController


#pragma mark - Table view
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Performance";
    else
        return @"Recovery";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return [performanceArray count];
    else
        return [recoveryArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
        cell.textLabel.text = [performanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = [recoveryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Prepare data to pass
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Audio Selection Segue"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        NowPlayingViewController *np = [segue destinationViewController];

        //Pass the selected audio title to the Now Playing View
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
        np.title = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
}

#pragma mark - didSelectRowAtIndexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Audio Selection Segue" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - Initialization
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Instantiate performanceArray
    performanceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Centering", nil];

    //Instantiate recoveryArray
    recoveryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Power Nap", nil];
}
```

Comment: There are 2 issues here: you want only 1 instance of NowPlaying view (at the moment you are instantiating new ones), and it is STILL playing the old audio (which implies that your NowPlaying views are working with class variables.) In order to solve the 2nd, we'll need to see code.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have been Instantiating new audio players. Do I create a 'Now Playing class" and pass data to it from the tableview? I added my header file and implementation file to the original post...Thanks!

Comment: Code for the Controller looks fine. Can you also paste the code for the parent Controller? Does the music continue playing when you pop it from the Navigation Controller?

Comment: Will add the parent controller now. Not sure I understand what you mean by 'popping' it. I use a push segue from the tableview cell to push my navigation to the UIView "Now Playing". When Im in the Now Playing view and go back using the navbar button, the audio still plays if that what you mean.

Comment: Ah you're using StoryBoarding! That changes things. In that case, see the 2nd part of my post. The first part won't apply because you're not actually in control of the instantiation of the Controller

Comment: :) Yes I see many tutorials regarding the non storyboarding way, but I wanted to attempt to use the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part is simple. Instead of instantiating a new NowPlayingViewController each time you want to push it to the navigation stack, just reuse an existing one. You will then need to pass the audio url through a property on the NowPlayingViewController.

```
@interface MyTableViewController {
     NowPlayingViewController *nowPlayingViewController;
}

@implementation MyTableViewController{
     ...
     nowPlayingViewController = [[nowPlayingViewController alloc]init];
     ...
     [nowPlayingViewController setAudio:@"urlToAudio"]
     this.navigationController.pushViewController(nowPlayingViewController);
     ...
}
```

Edit: the above was only relevant if you were instantiating the viewController as was implied. Turns out you were using storyboarding, which automatically instantiates new instances of the viewsControllers in segues. Therefore the problem is you are not stopping the music (see below).

---

Regarding the 2nd portion (music not stopping), you do not seem to be STOPPING the music anywhere. Do so, in "viewDidUnload", or "viewWillDisappear" delegate call, which gets called whenever the view is no longer in use.

---

New edit based on new requirements:

- you want the Now Playing view to control the music.
- you don't want the music to stop even if the Now Playing view is unloaded.

In this case, you must separate the AudioPlayer from the Now Playing view.

You should pass in the AudioPlayer from externally, each time the NowPlaying view is created. Optimally, you should have a class that maintains the application state of the music player.

```
@interface MusicPlayer : NSObject{        
}

// example
-(bool) isPlaying;
-(bool) isPaused;

-(void) play;
-(void) pause;
-(void) stop;
-(void) changeTrack;

-(NSString *)currentTrack;
//etc.
@end
```

Then, when you do your segue, instead of just telling your NowPlaying view which track to play, pass it the MusicPlayer instance instead.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Audio Selection Segue"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        NowPlayingViewController *np = [segue destinationViewController];

        //Pass the selected audio title to the Now Playing View
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];

        [self.player stop];
        [self.player changeTrack:@"urlToTrack"];
        [self.player play];

        np.player = self.player;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of your buttons controlling what to play etc, let your buttons simply send messages to your music player. With some NSNotification, you can even let the musicplayer send events to your views to update things like album name, track name, album art etc.

Comment: I see. Awesome! So the design I had in mind is very similar to the music.app. I want to be able to select audio from a tableview and control the audio in the now playing view, and still have the ability to go from Now Playing to the audio selection tableview and back again if I so decide. as of now I can on return to the Now Playing view if I select a new piece of audio. How would I begin to achieve this??

Comment: By the way I am new to stack overflow so I can't vote your answer up. Soon as I can I will.

Comment: @AndrewRynhard see my new edit. And no worries, as long as it answers your question, I will get points :)

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the quick and thorough answer! Going to implement that now. Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries. Just don't forget to mark question as answered if it solves the problem :)

Comment: I will as soon as I have the rep to do it. I'm new to stack overflow. But I'm kind of confused. Again I'm very new to iOS programming. Do I create a new nsobject for "MusicPlayer"?

Comment: Subclass NSObject, yes. I missed that.

Comment: Ok i'm going to have to do some studying. Not quite familiar with how I would go about creating my custom music player class with all its functions, and then how to use it haha.

Comment: It is exactly the same as how you have created your NowPlayingViewController (you are creating your own custom class). Instead of subclassing UIViewController you are subclassing NSObject instead. :)

Comment: So it has all the same coding I have for the audio player in nowplayingviewconttroller and then I import it in the now playing view controller?

Comment: mmm pretty much. It does not have to be the same, you can add whatever you want. 

It has to be imported into your TableViewController as well (since it has to pass it to your NowPlayingViewController). Definitely do some study on basics of creating classes in Obj-c

Comment: Watching a tutorial as we speak :) Appreciate all the help. I get the gist of it, just need to iron things out. Thanks again.

Comment: Quick question. I have successfully done as you said but  having a problem finding out how to use nsnotification to control the volume. Any suggestions?

Comment: To control the volume? From where? Notifications should only be sent FROM the musicplayer, not the other way around.

Comment: I am confused **Now, instead of your buttons controlling what to play etc, let your buttons simply send messages to your music player.** this was taken from the bottom of your answer.

Comment: Yes. So your buttons do not interact with [AVAudioPlayer]. You call [myMusicPlayer play] instead.

Comment: Yes they do and I  just found out how to notify the volume change as well. :)